# How do I set, via the lua C API, the environment table for a chunk of lua code prior to running it?

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-api

The interface for my game engine is built using a markup language and Lua, similar to HTML and javascript.  As such, visual elements will have handlers for UI events such as a mouse move or click, and each time a handler is to be run, the engine will check if it is compiled yet and if not will compile it via `luaL_loadstring`.  Handers can be shared either by element duplication or assignment (`this.onclick = that.onclick`).

How do I set the environment of a chunk of lua code before running it?  The idea is to make element- and event-specific data available to the chunk, and also to link to the environment of the parent UI element.  [Lua 5.2 changes](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.1) removed `lua_setfenv`, so I am not sure how to accomplish this.  The function [`lua_load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) allows specifying an environment, but seems to only be used for loading code and not running it.

Comment: I think you mean version 5.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.2):

> You can use load (or loadfile) to load a chunk with a different environment. (In C, you have to load the chunk and then change the value of its first upvalue.)

Setting upvalues is done with [`lua_setupvalue`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_setupvalue). So, load your code first, then push the new environment and call `lua_setupvalue` the same way you would have called `lua_setfenv` before:

```
luaL_loadfile(L, "file.lua");       /* load and compile handler */
lua_getglobal(L, "my_environment"); /* push environment onto stack */
lua_setupvalue(L, -2, 1);           /* pop environment and assign to upvalue#1 */
/* any other setup needed */
lua_pcall(L, ...);                  /* call handler */
```

Also, from the end of your question:

> The function `lua_load` allows specifying an environment, but seems to only be used for loading code and not running it.

This is not actually the case; `load` (the Lua function) lets you specify an environment, but `lua_load` (the C function) does not.

Also, while it is "only used for loading code, and not running it", this is the same as `luaL_loadstring` - indeed, `luaL_loadstring` is just a wrapper around it. `lua_load` is a lower-level API function that can be used to implement custom loaders (for example, loading code over the network, or from a compressed file). So if you're already comfortable loading code with `luaL_loadstring` before running it with `lua_pcall`, `lua_load` should look familiar.

Comment: Nice to see you around.

Comment: I have not been able to test it yet, but I've implemented your solution.  Thanks!

Comment: How would you do this in Lua 5.3? lua_setupvalue() always returns NULL when I try your code. :-(

Comment: How did you know to use -2 as the funcindex in lua_setupvalue()?