# Modify Lua Chunk Environment: Lua 5.2

Tags: lua

It is my understanding that in Lua 5.2 that environments are stored in upvalues named `_ENV`. This has made it really confusing for me to modify the environment of a chunk before running it, but after loading it.

I would like to load a file with some functions and use the chunk to inject those functions into various environments. Example:

```
chunk = loadfile( "file" )

-- Inject chunk's definitions
chunk._ENV = someTable -- imaginary syntax
chunk( )

chunk._ENV = someOtherTable
chunk( )
```

Is this possible from within Lua? The only examples I can find of modifying this upvalue are [with the C api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167986/how-do-i-set-via-the-lua-c-api-the-environment-table-for-a-chunk-of-lua-code-p) (another [example from C api](http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Change-value-of-upvalue-from-within-function-td7642150.html)), but I am trying to do this from within Lua. Is this possible?

Edit: I'm unsure of accepting answers using the debug library. The [docs state](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.10) that the functions may be slow. I'm doing this for efficiency so that entire chunks don't have to be parsed from strings (or a file, even worse) just to inject variable definitions into various environments.

Edit: Looks like this is impossible: [Recreating setfenv() in Lua 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290527/recreating-setfenv-in-lua-5-2?rq=1)

Edit: I suppose the best way for me to do this is to bind a C function that can modify the environment. Though this is a much more annoying way of going about it.

Edit: I believe a more natural way to do this would be to load all chunks into separate environments. These can be "inherited" by any other environment by setting a metatable that refers to a global copy of a chunk. This does not require any upvalue modification post-load, but still allows for multiple environments with those function definitions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recreating setfenv() in Lua 5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290527/recreating-setfenv-in-lua-5-2)

Comment: Note that in the link you inserted, there's a [comment by one of Lua authors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290527/recreating-setfenv-in-lua-5-2?rq=1#comment19850353_14290609)

Comment: I see the comment but I hardly know what he means. I don't have experience from 5.1 to understand. @akavel

Comment: uh, actually I'm also not 100% sure, but from what I understand, in practice this means roughly what you seem to have gotten from others already: that it's doable via debug lib or C API (and in fact, debug does use the C API), albeit made kinda difficult and nonobvious on purpose, so that it's not overused in regular day-to-day Lua code. And coming from lhf, the answer has high credibility and gives insight as to the original intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to allow a chunk to be run in different environments is to make this explicit and have it receive an environment. Adding this line at the top of the chunk achieves this:

`_ENV=...`

Now you can call `chunk(env1)` and later `chunk(env2)` at your pleasure.

There, no `debug` magic with upvalues.

Although it will be clear if your chunk contains that line, you can add it at load time, by writing a suitable reader function that first sends that line and then the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It does seem quite nice, but adding that line to files is poor for scripting. So the comment about inserting this line just before reading a file is really cool. I am going to go try this out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you want to avoid using the debug library, while you are happy to use a C function (neither is possible in a sandbox.)

It can be done using `debug.upvaluejoin`:

```
function newEnvForChunk(chunk, index)
  local newEnv = {}
  local function source() return newEnv end
  debug.upvaluejoin(chunk, 1, source, 1)
  if index then setmetatable(newEnv, {__index=index}) end
  return newEnv
end
```

Now load any chunk like this:

```
local myChunk = load "print(x)"
```

It will initially inherit the enclosing `_ENV`.  Now give it a new one:

```
local newEnv = newEnvForChunk(myChunk, _ENV)
```

and insert a value for 'x':

```
newEnv.x = 99
```

Now when you run the chunk, it should see the value for `x`:

```
myChunk()
```

=> `99`

Comment: Oh is it really an okay thing to do, to use the Debug library? I'm not actually sandboxing for a test environment, I'm doing this for a release build. Specifically I am using this in a game engine where separate environments act as components in an aggregate based model. Each component environment should have definitions of `Init`, `Update` and `Shutdown`. Ideally all local variables in each "component file" can be instanced into separate environments, which is why I was wanting to use chunks to inject into environments. Do you think there is a better approach, or is this acceptable?

Comment: I also slightly edited my question where I said I didn't want to accept debug library answers. Also can `debug.setupvalue` be used? It seems like this might be a lot simpler.

Comment: If it helps, I tried out `debug.setupvalue` and it worked perfectly! I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @RandyGaul If you have multiple chunks sharing the same `_ENV` (which is the default) then `debug.setupvalue` will affect all of them.  If you create independent `_ENV`s (with `debug.upvaluejoin`) then they will not affect each other.

Comment: @RandyGaul re debug functions begin slow: yes they are, but so is loading a new chunk.  And both are done only once at startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify your chunk (per LHF's great answer) here are two alternatives:

#### Set up a blank environment, then dynamically change its environment to yours

```lua
function compile(code)
   local meta = {}
   local env = setmetatable({},meta)
   return {meta=meta, f=load('return '..code, nil, nil, env)}
end

function eval(block, scope)
   block.meta.__index=scope
   return block.f()
end

local block = compile('a + b * c')
print(eval(block, {a=1, b=2, c=3})) --> 7
print(eval(block, {a=2, b=3, c=4})) --> 14
```

#### Set up a blank environment, and re-set its values with your own each time

```lua
function compile(code)
   local env = {}
   return {env=env, f=load('return '..code, nil, nil, env)}
end

function eval(block, scope)
   for k,_ in pairs(block.env) do block.env[k]=nil end
   for k,v in pairs(scope) do block.env[k]=v end
   return block.f()
end

local block = compile('a + b * c')
print(eval(block, {a=1, b=2, c=3})) --> 7
print(eval(block, {a=2, b=3, c=4})) --> 14
```

Note that if micro-optimizations matter, the first option is about 2✕ as slow as the `_ENV=...` answer, while the second options is about 8–9✕ as slow.